# How to render a web page with android jdk?

Tags: java, android

I want to show the web page normally,but still keep the user in my app,

how to make use of the available web render engines programmatically?

**UPDATE**

I'm now using the `webview` ,but can't render the page,reporting 404 page not found.

However,when I pack my project and run in another computer,it works like charm!

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a webview and implement webkitclient if needed.
More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Please explain your question. I cant understand that you want to open the webview with the URL or by the html code. Both of them is totally different. Please explain how do you want to open the webview in application by URL or by HTML

Answer (score -1):

You, as of now, probably let your app open the device web browser to let the user see the content of the URL, via an Intent Action.

Use your activity which uses a `WebView` and implements its own `WebKitClient`. Then you can make the user stay in your app and control what and how content is fetched.

@Achie has a nice link for you which explains how Web things work in Android.

To know how to work with `WebViews`, go to [this URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and read the nice article-cum-tutorial